# Node js Child_process not returning stdout

Tags: node.js

Not sure why this does not work, if I run a simple command such as cmd='ls -all' then I get the output back, but when I use this to run a command which takes some time to complete I don't get anything at all returned.

In this example, I am using lftp to mirror some folders and want to get the reply, if I run the command from the terminal then of course I see the output, but using child process I get nothing:

```
var childProcess = require('child_process');
var cmd = 'lftp sftp://user:password@somehost -e "mirror -R  --delete --parallel=5 /usr/share/scripts/ /volumes/folders/usr/share/;bye"';

childProcess.exec(cmd, function (error, stdout, stderr) {
    console.log('stdout:'+stdout);
    console.log('stderr:'+stderr);
    console.log('error:'+error);
});
```

I also tried the spawn method, nothing returned from that either:

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
var lftp = spawn('lftp',['sftp://user:password@somehost', '-e "mirror -R  --delete --parallel=5 /usr/share/scripts/ /volumes/folders/usr/share/;bye"']);
lftp.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log(data.toString());

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that lftp buffers its output.

To get around that you'll need to use unbuffer (http://expect.sourceforge.net/example/unbuffer.man.html) to send the output directly to stdout.